# How to convert this to razor synxtax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I trying this tutorial  http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/.

Because i'm using razor , i' new to razor, i couldn't i convert this line

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>; //This Line


        ko.applyBindings(document.body, viewModel);
        $("form").validate({ submitHandler: function() { viewModel.save() } });
    </script>
```

I tried converted like this but it's complain " Type expected"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = @new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)   //This line throw me error

    var viewModel = {
        gifts : ko.observableArray(initialData) 
    };

    ko.applyBindings(document.body, viewModel); 
</script>
```

Comment: Found out is cause by javascript error not Razor.  var initialData = "@(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var initialData = "@(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model))";


var viewModel = {
    gifts : ko.observableArray(initialData) 
};

ko.applyBindings(document.body, viewModel); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try replacing the problematic line with this :

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@{
  string inData = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
     var initialData = '@inData';

     var viewModel = {
         gifts : ko.observableArray(initialData) 
     };

    ko.applyBindings(document.body, viewModel); 
</script>
```